# InvalidArgumentError: indices[13,9] = 197491 is not in [0, 189722) [[node sequential_7

Tags: keras, model

## MODEL CNN

## create a list of the target columns

target_cols = [y_toxic,y_severe_toxic,y_obscene,y_threat,y_insult,y_identity_hate]

preds = []

for col in target_cols:

```
print('\n')

# set the value of y
y = col

# create a stratified split
X_train, X_eval, y_train ,y_eval = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.25,shuffle=True,
                                                random_state=5,stratify=y)

# cnn model
model = Sequential()
e = Embedding(189722, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix], 
              input_length=500, trainable=False)
model.add(e)
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


# compile the model
Adam_opt = Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam_opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, mode='min')
save_best = ModelCheckpoint('toxic.hdf', save_best_only=True, 
                           monitor='val_loss', mode='min')

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_eval, y_eval),
                    epochs=100, verbose=1,callbacks=[early_stopping,save_best])


# make a prediction on y (target column)
model.load_weights(filepath = 'toxic.hdf')

predictions = model.predict(X_test)
y_preds = predictions[:,0]

# append the prediction to a python list
preds.append(y_preds)
```

let me know this why it getting alike.... I tried ot reshape it still the same error

Comment: Your input shape does not match, try using the same shape as X_train instead of manually feeding a number

Comment: should I change the size of X_train ??

Comment: X_train.shape[0] should help, Probably you can refer here for more information: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270546/how-does-keras-embedding-layer-work